# Selenium- Webdriver script unable to recognize page load

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a script which uses driver.get() to lid a page in Internet explorer. Most of the pages in the application are identified as loaded, however since the past few weeks few pages are not recognized as loaded even though they have returned 200. This script was working in the past but somehow stopped working few weeks back. Anyone has any clue on this? I cannot even add any wait as I realize that while debugging it just gets stuck on the driver.get() statement.

Comment: Are you implying the page takes too much time to load

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this in our app before too. Front End messes with navigation, and it messes up driver.get(). I hat to navigate using javascript directly.

```
driver.executeScript("window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';");
```

That's in java, but whatever language binding you're in will have some way to execute JS. That string of JS will be the same across all bindings though.

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer, the security settings should be set. To set the security settings--> 
Open IE--> tools--> Internet Options--> Security--> here, for all the internet,intranet,Trusted sites and Restricted sites, disable the protected mode and apply and save the settings.

Hope this helps :)